# Most probable velocity of a mixture of gases

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, gas

We have the average, root mean square, and most probable velocities of a gas as

$v_{av}=\sqrt\frac{8KT}{\pi m}$  ;  $v_{rms}=\sqrt\frac{3KT}{m}$ ; $v_{mp}=\sqrt\frac{2KT}{m}$

For a mixture of two gases, I have derived the following :

$v_{av_{mixture}}=\frac{N_1v_{av_1}+N_2v_{av_2}}{N_1+N_2}$ , and $v_{rms}=\sqrt{\frac{3KT}{\left(\frac{N_1+N_2}{\frac{N_1}{m_1}+\frac{N_2}{m_2}}\right)}}$

Where $N$ is number of molecules and $m$ is mass of one molecule.

However, I can't find a way to derive the most probable velocity.

How do I define the most probable velocity $v_{mp}$ of a mixture? How can I obtain an expression for it?

Comment: You need to be careful not to confuse averages to do with speed and velocity as the average velocity of gas molecules is zero.

Comment: Add together the two probability distributions, weighted by the number of molecules of each species.  Maximize this joint distribution function.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Alright I take it back, the method I've mentioned won't work. My bad, will delete this answer @Chirag Swarnkar